# Xcode 9 New Edit Format Lines - How to remove?

Tags: xcode, text-editor

When collapsing code in Xcode editor there are now lines that enclose the collapsed methods, see image.[image]

I'm sure it is probably easy, like removing the line numbers that were added, but I have already wasted several hours simply trying to get my projects to build without hanging.  Evidently, there are a large number of "developers" at Apple whose job it is to aggravate the Xcode users with "enhancements" like this to new versions.  Thanks!